# React Context Provider doesn't update value props? Stuck with initial state?

Tags: reactjs, react-context

I am trying to do very basic stuff with React Context to learn it.  I'm not sure if/how this complicates things, but I'm doing this in a NextJS 13 project.  (I know server components are introduced here but I'm trying to simplify things by labeling everything with `'use client'`.  The goal is just to have a React Context with a simple string in it, and a function that allows you to change that string.  Here is the code in question:

Small file to define the TS type associated with my context's shape:

```js
'use client'

export type UserContextType = {
  updateUsername: (username: string) => void;
  username: string;
}
```

My top level `src/app/layout.tsx` component (the layout from which all other pages are rendered):

```js
'use client'

import './globals.css'
import { Inter } from 'next/font/google'
import { createContext, useState } from 'react'

import { UserContextType } from '@/contexts/UserContext'

const inter = Inter({ subsets: ['latin'] })

export const UserContext = createContext<UserContextType>({
  username: '',
  updateUsername: (newName: string) => { console.log(`needs implementation`); }
});

export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode
}) {
  const [username, setUsername] = useState<string>('');

  function updateUsername(_username: string) {
    setUsername(_username);
  }

  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body className={inter.className}>
        <UserContext.Provider value={{username, updateUsername}}>
          {children}
        </UserContext.Provider>
      </body>
    </html>
  )
}
```

My `login.tsx` component (so named because I want to expand this to a real project at some point) found at `src/pages/login`:

```js
'use client'

import React, { ReactNode, useContext, useState } from 'react';

import { UserContext } from '@/app/layout';

const Login = (): JSX.Element => {
  const [content, setContent] = useState<string>('');

  const userContext = useContext(UserContext);
  const username = userContext?.username;
  const updateUsername = userContext?.updateUsername;

  function click() {
    updateUsername(content);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      {username && <>Logged in as {username}</>}
      <input
        onChange={(evt) => setContent(evt.target.value)}
        value={content}
      />
      <button
        onClick={() => click()}
      >
        Button
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Login;
```

I can read the **initial** values of the Context from `createContext...` but **not** the values passed to the Provider.  In other words, in the `Login` component I can see whatever value I put into the initial value of `username` and I can run the initial version of `updateUsername`, in other words I see "needs implementation" in the console.  But the values I pass to the provider are ignored.

What am I doing wrong and how does one use React Context to get the provider to pass on correct values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't realize at the time of asking this question, that NextJS 13.x permits developers to use the old 12.x file structure in parallel with the new.  The `layout.tsx` file will only apply to pages that are placed in the new 13.x file structure, e.g. in `src/app/my-page/page.tsx`.  My page files were still in the old `pages/` directory, and this was very confusing to figure out because NextJS will still merrily route to those pages defined the old way without complaint, giving no indication of why the `layout.tsx` changes aren't being picked up.  This is described to in the Next docs (though I can't seem to recall/find where off the top of my head now).

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to create another function for Provider: `UserContextProvider`.

```js
'use client'

import './globals.css'
import { Inter } from 'next/font/google'
import { createContext, useState } from 'react'

import { UserContextType } from '@/contexts/UserContext'

const inter = Inter({ subsets: ['latin'] })

export const UserContext = createContext<UserContextType>({
  username: '',
  updateUsername: (newName: string) => { console.log(`needs implementation`); }
});

export default UserContextProvider = ({children}: {children: React.ReactNode}) => {
  const [username, setUsername = useState("");
  
  const updateUsername = (_username: string) => {
    setUsername(_username);
  }
  
  return (
    <UserContext.Provider value={{username, updateUsername}}>
      {children}
     </UserContext.Provider>
  );
}

export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode
}) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body className={inter.className}>
        <UserContextProvider>
          {children}
        </UserContextProvider>
      </body>
    </html>
  )
}
```

Then, in the Login component, you could do something like this:

```js
'use client'

import React, { ReactNode, useContext, useState } from 'react';

import { UserContext } from '@/app/layout';

const Login = (): JSX.Element => {
  const {username, updateUsername} = useContext(UserContext);

  return (
    <div>
      {username && <>Logged in as {username}</>}
      <input
        onChange={(evt) => updateUsername(evt.target.value)}
        value={username}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export default Login;
```